# Which function to deflate a http request?

Tags: php, http, gzip, zlib

I make a HTTP POST request to a remote service which requires the post body to be "deflated" (and `Content-encoding: deflate` should be sent in headers). From my understanding, this is covered in [RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950). Which php function should I use to be compatible?

- gzencode
- gzdeflate
- gzcompress

Comment: You want `gzdeflate()`. Isn't it obvious from the name? If not, the documentation says it, too.

Comment: @Barmar: gzdeflate'd strings don't work on their side, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: You use whatever decompression the request headers say to use in the accept-encoding header.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm fine with snide remarks, unless they are ignorant at the same time. The correct answer below.

Comment: This is an excellent question. Zlib functions are a mess and the PHP implementation is not particularly intuitive.

Comment: So, There is no bult-in func in php to decode http deflated msg ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Content-Encoding: deflate` requires data to be presented [using the zlib structure (defined in RFC 1950), with the deflate compression algorithm (defined in RFC 1951)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding).

Consider

```
<?php
    $str = 'test';

    $defl = gzdeflate($str);
    echo bin2hex($defl), "\n";

    $comp = gzcompress($str);
    echo bin2hex($comp), "\n";
?>
```

This gives us:

```
2b492d2e0100
789c2b492d2e0100045d01c1
```

so the `gzcompress` result is the `gzdeflate`'d buffer preceded by `789c`, which appears to be a valid zlib header

```
0111     |  1000       |  11100   |  0        |  10
CINFO    |  CM         |  FCHECK  |  FDICT    |  FLEVEL
7=32bit  |  8=deflate  |          |  no dict  |  2=default algo
```

and followed by 4 bytes of checksum. This is what we're looking for.

To sum it up,

- `gzdeflate` returns a raw deflated buffer (RFC 1951)
- `gzcompress` returns a deflated buffer wrapped in zlib stuff (RFC 1950)
- `Content-Encoding: deflate` requires a wrapped buffer, that is, **use `gzcompress` when sending deflated data**.

Note the confusing naming: `gzdeflate` is *not* for `Content-Encoding: deflate` and `gzcompress` is *not* for `Content-Encoding: compress`. Go figure!